# How to reference a standard (Eurocode) Harvard Style in Latex

Tags: bibtex

does anyone know how to write a citation for a standard in the below style?

Information:

**Name of Standard Body/Institution:** British Standards Institution

**(Year of publication):** 2003

**Standard number:** BS 5950-8:2003

**Title (this should be in italics):** Structural use of steelwork in building: code of practice for fire resistant design.

**Place of publication:** London

**Publisher:** British Standards Institution

Reference should look like this in the bibliography

British Standards Institution. (2003) BS 5950-8:2003. *Structural use of steelwork in building: code of practice for fire resistant design.* London, British Standards Institution.

And the in-text citation should look like this: (British Standards Institution, 2003)